# How to automate an application with constant properties for whole page via AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I am automating an application using AutoIt where the properties of whole page are constant.

e.g. Instance, Co-ordinates,text etc are same for button,dropdown etc.
Also, the id for all web elements is blank. Only unique property is ControlClick Coords.

```
#include <Constants.au3>
run("C:\Program Files (x86)\CashRBrowserClient\CashRBrowserClient.exe")
WinWaitActive("Sears Call Center","","10")
WinActive("Sears Call Center")
If WinExists("Sears Call Center") Then
Send("username{TAB}")
Send("password{Enter}")
EndIf
sleep(500)
ControlClick("Sears Call Center", "", "WebViewHost5", "Left")
```

also tried,

```
If WinExists("Sears Call Center") Then
;WinActivate("[CLASS:CEFCLIENT];[Instance:1]","[ClassnameNN:WenHost1]")
;sleep(500)
;MouseClick("Left",200,367)
;EndIf`enter code here`
```

But no luck apart of login.

Need help.

Answer (score 0):

The WinActive function checks if a window is active and returns True or False. In this code, this function is doing basically nothing.

[WinActive](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActive.htm)

It is always a good idea use a WinActivate before the WinWaitActive to avoid problems with the program waiting for ever. A better solution would be:

```
While Not WinActive($hWin)
    WinActivate($hwin)
    Sleep(500)
WEnd
```

[WinActivate](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinActivate.htm)

[WinWaitActive](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWaitActive.htm)

Try this:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"

Run("C:\Program Files (x86)\CashRBrowserClient\CashRBrowserClient.exe")

WinWait("Sears Call Center")
While Not WinActive("Sears Call Center")
    WinActivate("Sears Call Center")
    Sleep(500)
WEnd

Send($username)
Sleep(100)
Send("{TAB}")
Sleep(100)
Send($password)
Sleep(100)
Send("{Enter}")
Sleep(100)
```